# Find a file matching a pattern, but not in directory matching another pattern

Tags: linux, find

I have a source tree having some directories with names ending with `-old`, which are kept as a reference when rewriting components that are in them. There's also a `Makefile` that just `find`s all `*.cpp` files in subfolders of current directory and compiles them into single executable (yes, I know, it ain't any great build system, but it works quite fine... except the `-old`s).

So, I am using this to get list of all `*.cpp` files:

```
SOURCES=$(shell find . -name "*.cpp" -print)
```

How can I tell `find` to look for all `*.cpp` files, that do not have `*-old*` in their path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.cpp' ! -path '*-old*'
```

Comment: Ok, obviously. I have no idea why I didn't come up with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type d -name "*-old" -prune -o -name "*.cpp" -print
```